# I am new with angular js. I am trying to create an Edit mode on button click in ng-grid

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

here is my code.

```
$scope.Editmode = false;

$scope.OpportunitiesData = [{
    Name:"E123", Age:"13", Gender: "Male", Opportunities:"5"
}, {
    Name:"E123", Age:"12", Gender: "Male", Opportunities:"42"
}];

$scope.grdOpportunities = {
    data: 'OpportunitiesData',
    columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'Name',
            displayName: 'Name',
            width: '20%'
        },
        {
            field: 'Age',
            displayName: 'Age',
            width: '20%'
        },
        {
            field: 'Gender',
            displayName: 'Gender',
            width: '20%'
        },
        {
            filed: 'Opportunities',
            displayName: 'Number of opportunities',
            width: '20%',
            cellTemplate: '<input type="textbox" data-ng-model="row.entity.NumberOfOpportunities" ng-show="Editmode">'+
                          '<span ng-show="!Editmode">{{row.entity.NumberOfOpportunities}}<span>'
        },
        {
            width: '20%',
            cellTemplate: '<a class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="grdEditClick()" ng-show="!Editmode">' +
                          '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a>' +
                          '<a class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="GetOpportunityDetails()" ng-show="Editmode">' +
                          '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Update</a>' +
                          '<a class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="grdCancelClick()" ng-show="Editmode">' +
                          '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</a>'
        }],
    enableColumnResize: true,
    enableFiltering: true
};

$scope.grdEditClick = function () {
    $scope.Editmode = true;
    };
```

The problem i'm facing is that in this case when EDIT is clicked all the rows move to edit mode. 
I want only the ROW in which the EDIT button was clicked to move to edit mode and the rest of the grid should be disable until cancel or update is given.

Comment: HTML please where you are calling grdEditClick?

Comment: its given in the cellTemplate data-ng-click="grdEditClick()"

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle link for it?

Comment: Sorry, did not get time for that. I understand that here the variable "$scope.Editmode" which i'm using to set the ng-show is common for all the rows. Any idea how to set ng-show property for a particular row on button click?